# Storing Time Ranges in MySQL and Determine if Current Time is within Time Range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, time

I have a database table storing opening hours of a shop as a time range in TIME format. Eg if the shop's opening hours are '9am-5pm', there will be 2 columns 'hours_open' and 'hours_close' where I store 9:00 in 'hours_open' and 17:00 in 'hours_close'. To determine if the shop is currently open or closed, I will run the query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM shop 
 WHERE CAST(NOW() AS TIME) BETWEEN hours_open AND hours_close;
```

What I need to do now, is to accommodate shops with opening hours that go past midnight, like 9pm - 3am. Additionally, the shops can have different opening hours on different days, eg: Mon-Thurs: 9pm-3am, Fri-Sun: 9pm-5am.

Now I am stumped. How should I proceed? I can have a pair of 'hours_open' and 'hours_close' for each day, eg: 'mon_hours_open', 'mon_hours_close', 'tue_hours_open', 'tue_hours_close' ...

But how do I handle opening hours that go past midnight like 9pm-5am?

Any insights? I'm using PHP with Codeigniter framework if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to check the hours if they were stored in a separate table, something like

```
shop_working_hours (
  shop_id int FK,
  day_of_week int,
  hours_open time,
  hours close time,
  PK (shop_id, day_of_week)
)
```

That way the query might be like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM shop s
  INNER JOIN shop_working_hours h ON s.id = h.shop_id
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN h.hours_close > h.hours_open THEN
      h.day_of_week = DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) AND
      CAST(NOW() AS time) >= h.hours_open AND CAST(NOW() AS time) < h.hours_close
    ELSE
      h.day_of_week = DAYOFWEEK(NOW() - 1) AND
      CAST(NOW() AS time) >= h.hours_open OR CAST(NOW() AS time) < h.hours_close
  END
```

If, however, you would rather stick with having multiple columns like `*_hours_open` and `*_hours_close` for every day of week in the same table, i.e. the `shop` table, then the filter condition would most probably have to be more complex, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM shop s
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS day_of_week
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 5
    UNION ALL SELECT 6
    UNION ALL SELECT 7
  ) h
WHERE
  CASE h.day_of_week
    WHEN 1 THEN
      CASE
        WHEN s.mon_hours_close > s.mon_hours_open THEN
          h.day_of_week = DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) AND
          CAST(NOW() AS time) >= s.mon_hours_open AND
          CAST(NOW() AS time) < s.mon_hours_close
        ELSE
          h.day_of_week = DAYOFWEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND
          CAST(NOW() AS time) >= s.mon_hours_open OR
          CAST(NOW() AS time) < s.mon_hours_close
      END
    WHEN 2 THEN
      CASE
        WHEN s.tue_hours_close > s.tue_hours_open THEN
        …  /* same for Tuesday */
      END
    …  /* and for all the other days of week */
  END
```

Comment: great code, as i try to figure out how the code works, i am wondering if this will take into account the different days of the week as I see no references to days

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Oops, seems like I missed that bit. I'll review my answer in about half an hour (I think).

Comment: For example, the shop is open from Mon 9pm till Tue 3am, and Tue 9pm till Wed 3am. In this case, hours_open_mon = 2100, hours_close_mon = 0300, and hours_open_tue = 2100, hours_close_tue = 0300. If the time now is Mon 11pm, we go into the ELSE branch and the shop is seen as open. If the time now is Tue 1am, there is no code that tells it that we should still compare NOW() with hours_close_mon instead of hours_close_tue

Comment: Great, got it to work nicely with additional conditional statements to make it more precise and general :)

Answer (score 1):

How about two entries in your shop table for such days, one that goes Monday 09:00:00 - 11:59:59 and another that goes Tuesday 12:00:00 - 03:00:00?

Comment: i am wondering if this will create 14 more columns (7 days x 2) and degrade performance?

Comment: It would create more rows, not more columns. The difference between 14 rows and 7 is really not very much. And I wouldn't worry too much about micro-optimization of performance until performance becomes a problem. Selecting a single row out of a table like this should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You could have three fields in your `opening` table:

```
opening
    day_opens       <--- what day the shop opens
    hour_opens      <--- what hour the shop opens
    duration_open   <--- how many hours it stays open
```

So cheching if it is open now (or at a certain day and time), it would be a condition like:

```
WHERE (   day_opens = Day(NOW()) 
      AND hourOpens <= Hour(NOW())
      AND Hour(NOW()) < hourOpens + duration_open 
      )
   OR (   day_opens + 1 = Day(NOW())
      AND Hour(NOW()) < hourOpens + duration_open - 24
      )
```

or even better in one condition:

```
WHERE day_opens * 24 + hourOpens    <= Day(NOW()) * 24 + Hour(NOW())
  AND Day(NOW()) * 24 + Hour(NOW()) <  day_opens * 24 + hourOpens + hourOpens
```

Comment: i dont the code accounts for different opening hours on different days. seems like the above code works nicely for shops if they have the same opening hours each day.. but I'm learning alot from your approach!

Answer (score 0):

There are very good ideas in: Is a given booking period available?
(http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#576).
It helped me in a similar situation.

Comment: Please [provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Summarize the main points directly in your answer; include the link only as a reference, an acknowledgement or for further information. At least include some sample code directly in your answer.